# Python - enumerate a multidimensional list

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, enumeration

Let's say I have a multidimensional array, `foobar`:

```py
foobar = [[[0, 1, 2],
           [3, 4, 5, 6],
           [7, 8]],
          [[9, 10],
           [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
           [16, 17, 18],
           [19, 20, 21, 22]],
          [[23, 24, 25],
           [26, 27]]]
```

Note that `foobar` is jagged.

The thing I need to do is replace each number in `foobar` with a tuple containing that number and its exact position in `foobar`. I also need to be able to do this when the number of dimensions and whether or not `foobar` is jagged is unknown.

Here is something similar, except it only works for 2 dimensions:

```py
def enum_multidim(data):
    for i, a in enumerate(data):
        for j, b in enumerate(a):
            yield (i, j, b)
```

Is there a user-defined function that can do what I said above?

Comment: you mean a tuple like `(x, y, z, value)`?, also have you tried anything at all?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes to both.

Comment: There will be a user-defined function as soon as you write it.
I expect that you meant to ask for a built-in function; no, there is not.  You say that you've tried something -- then please include that [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE) to make this a useful question.

Comment: @Prune By user-defined, I mean written by yourself and not from any module.

Comment: Well, what did you try and what happened? This seems pretty straight-forward, you can write the nested loop with enumerate, creating a new list or, I suppose, mutating the original list in-place. Seems

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga See my edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive generator for an arbitrary number of dimensions

**Code**

```
def enum_multidim(data, t = None):
    if t is None:
        t = ()
    if not isinstance(data, list):
        yield t + (data,)
    else:
        for i, v in enumerate(data):
            yield from enum_multidim(v, t + (i,))
```

**Test**

```
for t in enum_multidim(foobar):
    print(t)

# Out:
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 2, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 3)
(0, 1, 1, 4)
(0, 1, 2, 5)
(0, 1, 3, 6)
(0, 2, 0, 7)
(0, 2, 1, 8)
(1, 0, 0, 9)
(1, 0, 1, 10)
(1, 1, 0, 11)
(1, 1, 1, 12)
(1, 1, 2, 13)
(1, 1, 3, 14)
(1, 1, 4, 15)
(1, 2, 0, 16)
(1, 2, 1, 17)
(1, 2, 2, 18)
(1, 3, 0, 19)
(1, 3, 1, 20)
(1, 3, 2, 21)
(1, 3, 3, 22)
(2, 0, 0, 23)
(2, 0, 1, 24)
(2, 0, 2, 25)
(2, 1, 0, 26)
(2, 1, 1, 27)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was thinking along the lines of this.

Comment: @RudraPatel--yes, your posted code shows you were on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

So, I saw DarryIG's answer and modified it to fit my style:

```py
def get_dims(data): # some other function I use
    if not isinstance(data, itertypes):
        return 0
    return get_dims(data[0]) + 1
def enum_multidim(data, index = []):
    if get_dims(data) == 0:
        return index + [data]
    return [enum_multidim(x, index + [i]) for i, x in enumerate(data)]
```

Credit will go to him. Thanks so much!